# Cannot read XML data using XPATH when there is no valid namespace name available

Tags: node.js, xml, typescript, xpath, xml-namespaces

I am working on typescript based node program and trying to read XML data from already existing xml file (this file is getting downloaded from third party location) . I use xpath in this scenario (https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath)

Below is the root node of XML file

```
<bookstore xmlns="https://www.example.com/schema/papers/doc/5.0" id="5001" name ="amber" >
```

Below is the sample code

```
      var somePath = //abc
      var result = xpath.evaluate(
          somePath,            // xpathExpression 
          someDocument,        // contextNode 
          {“”: “https://www.example.com/schema/papers/doc/5.0”},// namespaceResolver 
          xpath.XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, // resultType 
          null                        // result 
       );
```

However I couldn’t able to retrieve any data with above code. I found that this code doesn't resolve the name space.Reason seems that there is no valid namespace available to identify current namespace.

For example if third party XML have namespace such as xmlns:abc=https://www.example.com/schema/papers/doc/5.0 I can simply use it under **xpath.eveluate** (e.g. {“abc”: “https://www.example.com/schema/papers/doc/5.0”}) and retrieve required data.

Is there any way to retrieve data from this kind of namespaces with no name? Please be kind enough to shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eventually I have came up with hack to fix this issue. I have used something like below to add namespace name and it solved my issue. var res = str.replace("xmlns", "xmlns:ns"); so I can denote name {“ns”: “https://www.example.com/schema/papers/doc/5.0”}